# Modeling binding taking forever

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a `UserFilter` class as a parameter on a Web API 2 action method which takes ~30 seconds to complete binding. I've already stepped into the `UserFilter` class as its being created and it takes no time at all instantiate, but once its created Web API is doing something in the background accounting for the ~30 seconds and then finally starts executing my action method.

I've setup the `UserFilter` on an MVC controller in this same project and it bind instantly with no delays. It's just Web API that is having this issue.

---

What can I do to figure out what Web API is doing in the background?

Is there an event I can latch onto in the binding lifecycle?

```
[Route("all")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers([FromBody]UserFilter filter)
{
    // takes ~30 seconds before a breakpoint hits this next line
    filter = UserFilter.InitializeFilter(filter);

    var userList = await UserRepository.GetUsers(filter).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok(new JsonResponse(new { Users = userList, Pager = filter.Pager }));
}

public class UserFilter : BaseFilter<UserFilter, User>
{
    // DO NOT REMOVE: default constructor needed for model binding
    public UserFilter() : base() { }

    public UserFilter(int? pageSize)
        : base(pageSize)
    {
    }
    ...
}

public abstract class BaseFilter<TFilterType, TEntity>
{
    // default constructor needed for model binding
    public BaseFilter()
    {
        Pager = new Pager(null);
        Init();
    }

    public BaseFilter(int? pageSize)
    {
        Pager = new Pager(pageSize);
        Init();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with Web API 2 model binding code. The class `QueryMutatorCondition` had a constructor that took generic `Predicate<>` and `Func<>` as parameters. This is what Web API was choking on.

For unknown reasons it continued to attempt to bind to the `QueryMutators` property (member of the `BaseFilter` class) even though I told it to ignore it with the attribute. The fix was to change the access modifier to `internal` instead of `public` to prevent Web API from attempting to bind to it.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public List<QueryMutatorCondition<TFilterType, TEntity>> QueryMutators { get; set; }
```

became:

```
internal List<QueryMutatorCondition<TFilterType, TEntity>> QueryMutators { get; set; }
```